# Редактирование стилей в Open Cart

Tags: opencart

Проблема следующая, хочу поменять цветовую схему на сайте, движок OpenC
Принцип немного знаю, работать с таблицей стилей умею. Но тут немного другая ситуация. К примеру, хочу поменять цвет кнопки, но ее цвет подтягивается не с файла стилей, а сразу с файла index.

На прикрепленных фото это видно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в самом файле index, такого нету. Кто знает с помощью чего оно гинерируется, и где искать эти стили, что-бы изменить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сперва посмотрите в файле /catalog/view/theme/ВАША_ТЕКУЩАЯ_ТЕМА/template/common/header.tpl (или header.twig, в зависимости от версии OC)
Если в этих файлах ничего подобного нет, то надо смотреть модификаторы OCmod (VqMod), которые вносят изменения в этот файл.

Comment: Спасибо большое) Нашла вот такую строку `a, a:visited, a b {color:#<?php echo $this->config->get('themer_main_color'); ?>;}`, не подскажите где эти переменные задаются?

Comment: Скорее всего, в настройках вашего шаблона, где-нибудь в админке ОС. Либо смотрите документацию к шаблону, либо в админке ищите что может быть связано с "темой" в модулях, настройке магазина.